# How do I apply sliced array values to other array variables when its not a dimension, but a separate array?

Tags: python, arrays, dimensions

I'm new at Python programming, so forgive me if this is a simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer to it. I have 3 arrays from a dataset as shown below. I am basically trying to plot the date and count of lightning at a certain position, but first need to get the dates and counts to match that position.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as n
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
import netCDF4



data = Dataset("ISS_LIS_SC_B0.1_20170826_NQC_03687.nc", mode="r")
time = data.variables['one_second_TAI93_time']


dates    =netCDF4.num2date(time[:], time.units)
counts   =data.variables['one_second_event_count'][:]
position =data.variables["lightning_event_location"][:][3646:3783] 

###position sliced to the specific latitude and longitude needed for my 
domain

#Array shapes:

dates.shape
(5556, )
counts.shape
(5556, 2)
position.shape
(137, 2)
```

All this is fine except I'm used to working with arrays that contain the latitude or longitude as dimensions, where I can just slice them within that array. Here, they are in their own separate position array. In this case, how do I just get the dates and counts for just the specified positions if it's not included in their array dimensions?

I tried creating my own empty array array with multiple dimensions, but I get: ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Don't you just have to take the corresponding elements (i.e. `[3646:3783]`) from `dates` and `counts`?

Comment: @Paul Panzer Since the dates and counts arrays are different shapes than position array, I won't know if [3646:3783] are the correct corresponding values. Also, if it helps, when not sliced the position array is shape: (9464, 2)

Comment: `dates` and `counts` have compatible shapes but it is indeed strange that `positions` are different. Do you happen to know why `counts` has two columns?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. When I do an ncdump on the file it shows one_second_event_count to have: one_second_dimension and processing_stage_dimension. I'm not sure why it's arranged like this.

Comment: The position array dimensions are: event_dimension, and lat/lon_dimensions

Comment: Beats me. I assume you are aware of [this document](https://ghrc.nsstc.nasa.gov/pub/lis/iss/doc/isslis_dataset.pdf)? Maybe it can help?

Comment: Funny, I actually had that open, and yup that's where the data's coming from. Thank you for trying